# Jackson deserialization ignore properties does not work properly with @JsonView

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, json-deserialization

I'm using [**spring-framework 4.2.5**](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) and [**Jackson 2.6.3**](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/) in my application. I use `@jsonView` for proper `serializer` entities. But It don't work properly for `deserializer`. For example I have an entity as follow:

```
public class A {

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private int a;

    @JsonView(View.Detail.class)
    private int b

    /*
     * Getters And Setters
     */
}
```

Now I have a controller as follow:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/a")
public class AController {

     @RequestMapping("/add")
     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
     public void add(@RequestBoddy A a)
     {
         // do Something
     }

}
```

When I send a json as follow to this method:

```
{
   "a": 1,
   "b": 2
}
```

Because I use `View.Summary.class` JsonView for this method, It must ignore `b`, But it does not.

I use a config in Object mapper as follow:
`objectMapper.enable(DeserializerFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES)`

**Where is the problem**?

Comment: Pretty sure the annotation is JsonView not JsonViwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@JsonView(View.Summary.class)` on the parameter:

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
public void add(@RequestBoddy @JsonView(View.Summary.class) A a) {
    // do Something
}
```

And also, use *Nullable* types for your *DTO*s:

```
public class A {
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Integer a;

    @JsonView(View.Detail.class)
    private Integer b

    /*
     * Getters And Setters
     */
}
```

Otherwise, you won't be able to tell the *Default Values* and *Missing Values* apart.

Comment: Are you sure it's JsonViwe and not JsonView?